# I want to print the last 'n' elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a JavaScript function to get the last 'n' elements of the array. If array has 6 elements and if user gives 4, it has to return last 4 elements. If user gives ‘n’ which is greater than the number of elements in the array, then it should return all elements.

The problem is if If the array has 8 elements and I give number 10. The result is : `undefined undefined 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

I want to display only the numbers without "undefined".

Thanks

HTML code

The array is :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

        <br>
        x:
        <input type="number" id="x" value="2" >
        <br>
        <button onclick="elements()"> Get the elements </button>

        <p id="result"></p>

    <script src="ex10.js"></script>
```

JavaScript code

```
 var Elements = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

    function elements(){
    var x = document.getElementById("x").value;

    for(var i=Elements.length - x; i <=Elements.length-1; i++)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += Elements[i] + " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: Please fix the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) of your question.

Comment: `array.slice(0,-n)`

Comment: You was getting `undefined` because when you declare `var i = Elements.length - x` you will ge negative numbers on `i` when `x > Elements.length`. So you will access indexes below `0` on the array (example: `Elements[-1]`) that will thrown the `undefined` values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[In a javascript array, how do I get the last 5 elements, excluding the first element?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6473858/90527)", "[Extracting last n elements from array without disturbing original array](//stackoverflow.com/q/54024039/90527)"

Answer (score 13):

You could take `slice` with a negative count from the end. Then `join` the elements for a formatted output.

Some links:

- [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

console.log(array.slice(-4).join(' '));
```

Answer (score 9):

Try using [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method with a negative start index:

```js
var Elements = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

var last4 = Elements.slice(-4)

console.log(last4)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to achieve why you need, for example by using `.slice()`, `.map()` etc.

If you need to stick to `for` loops, thn `Math.min()` can come handy:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const elX = document.getElementById("x");
const elR = document.getElementById("result");

function elements() {
  const x = parseInt(elX.value, 10); // use parseInt with radix!
  const min = Math.min(arr.length, x);
  let html = "";
  for (var i = arr.length - min; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
    html += arr[i] + " ";
  }
  elR.innerHTML = html; // Insert into DOM only once!
}
```

```html
x: <input type="number" id="x" value="2">
<button onclick="elements()">Get the last N elements</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Here's the example using `.slice()` and `.map()`

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const elX = document.getElementById("x");
const elR = document.getElementById("result");

function elements() {
  const x = parseInt(elX.value, 10);
  elR.innerHTML = arr.slice(-x).map(n => `Item:${n}`).join('<br>');
}
```

```html
x: <input type="number" id="x" value="2">
<button onclick="elements()">Get the last N elements</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: _"thn `Math.min()` can come handy"_ - Why?

Comment: I'm aware of why you're using it. But TO is obviously a beginner, and yet nobody tries to explain their solutions, or the problems with the code from TO, or ...

Comment: well .. i did : (answer below) "You want to make sure i is within range of the array. Elements.length - x needs to be equal or superior to 0."

Comment: @Andreas thx yes. Usually I review my own answers when done with the general picture, but glad to have another pair of eyes °.0

Answer (score 1):

You can just reassign x to be the length of the array if x is greater than the size of the array. Now you will at most print the entire array and at least print x.

```
var x = document.getElementById("x").value;

if(x > Elements.length)  // add this
    x = Elements.length;

for(var i=Elements.length - x; i <=Elements.length-1; i++)
{
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += Elements[i] + " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
const count = 5;
var Elements = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
var result = Elements.slice(count > Elements.length ? 0 : Elements.length - count,Elements.length)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const drivers = ['Sally', 'Bob', 'Freddy', 'Claudia'];

  function returnFirstTwoDrivers(drivers) {
  return drivers.slice(0,2) 
  }

    function returnLastTwoDrivers(drivers) {
    return drivers.slice(-2)
  }
  

document.getElementById("mocha").innerHTML = 'ARRAY 1: ' + returnFirstTwoDrivers(drivers) + '<br/>ARRAY 2: ' + returnLastTwoDrivers(drivers);
```

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crB4r.png)

Comment: When adding an answer to an older question with many existing answers, it is important to add an explanation of how yours differs from others, or you may get downvotes. For instance, this answer uses `slice`, as do several other existing answers, including the most upvoted. Also, the answer uses an example array that is different than the original question's, which makes it harder for the curious to compare to other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure `i` is within range of the array. `Elements.length - x` needs to be equal or superior to 0.

Like other said you can (should ?) use slice but since you seem to be practicing with for loops then you better stick with it.

```
var Elements = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

function elements(){
    var x = document.getElementById("x").value;

    for(var i=Math.max(Elements.length - x, 0); i <=Elements.length-1; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += Elements[i] + " ";
    }

}
```