# Is there a way to use .filter() to get the last X number of elements/indices in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, indices

> I need a way to filter through an array and return the last x number (or most recently added) of elements/indices of that array. I know .pop() could work, but I’m not sure how to combine pop and filter, nor how to return a certain number of last elements/indices.

Comment: Do you mean [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)? `[0,1,2,3].slice(-2) // [2,3]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to print the last 'n' elements of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293455/i-want-to-print-the-last-n-elements-of-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

```js
// This is what you should use
const getNLastItems = (n, array) => array.slice(-n)
console.log(getNLastItems(3, [1,2,3,4,5]))

// But if you want you can use filter to do that as well
const getNLastItemsWithFilter = (n, array) => array.filter((_, i) => array.length - i <= n)
console.log(getNLastItemsWithFilter(3, [1,2,3,4,5]))
```